# Atributo enabled dos elementos da HTML5 pertence a qual interface?

Tags: html, css, html5

Percebi que alguns elementos da HTML aceitam o atributo enabled, mas não consegui identificar na W3C qual a interface que mostra a sua possibilidade de sua utilização. Obrigada!

Comment: você quer saber quais elementos (tags) usam o `enable`?

Comment: Não, seria complexo demais. O que gostaria de saber é qual a interface (Ex: interface HTMLELement, interface Element, interface Node..) que nos mostra a possibilidade de uso do atributo enable pelos elementos. (Ex: <html enable>, <html disabled>). Obrigada!

Comment: Acho que entendi... Normalmente os elementos que aceitam o `enable` e `disabled` são botões, inputs, e caixas de texto, em geral tudo relacionado a formulários. Mas não tenho certeza se outros tipos de elementos aceitam essa propriedade.

Comment: Veja este link: http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/elements.html#htmlelement ele possui a interface de HTMLElement, mas nessa interface não existe nenhum atributo que me leve ao uso de enable/disabled. Acredito que seu uso esteja em outra interface. Mas, qual é essa interface? Obrigada =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe atributo `enabled` no HTML. Existe uma propriedade [`.enabled` na API de Audio](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-html51-20151008/semantics.html#dom-audiotrack-enabled), e existe um pseudo-seletor [`:enabled` na API de CSS](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-html51-20151008/semantics.html#selector-enabled).

O `enabled` que seria de esperar em elementos de `<form>` e [que o CSS têm](https://jsfiddle.net/zgown4xn/), "diz-se" `enabled` mas quer dizer-se "não-disabled". Ou seja, é a presença ou ausência do atributo `disabled` que indica se um elemento está ativo (`enabled`) ou não.

Comment: Sergio, posso usar pseudo-class em qualquer elemento da HTML? Obrigada =)

Comment: @IngridFarabulini os elementos que respondem ao `:enabled` são `["button", "input", "select", "textarea", "optgroup", "option", "menuitem", "fieldset"]`. Está no link que coloquei em cima, na resposta.

Comment: havia visto o link que passou, mas notei que também é possível desabilitar, por exemplo, o elemento html no IE. Também entendi que o 'disabled' não é um atributo do elemento. Então aqui no Brasil, quando o 'disabled' estiver presente em um elemento, devo definir que o elemento tem uma pseudo-class ou é outro nome? Seletor? Obrigada =)

Comment: Veja esse link: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/HTML/Attributes Nele, o disabled é considerado um atributo.

Comment: @IngridFarabulini existe um atributo `disabled` sim, o que não existe é o `enabled`. O pseudo-seletor é para o CSS e ai sim há `:enabled`.